# Combine data from multiple tables using indirect references in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am needing to combine all student attendance in one chart. I have tried Query, Vlookup, and Index Match - nothing seems to get the results I want. I need something to search first and last name and return all attendance from all sheets. I would like to use something like CHOOSE and INDIRECT due to the future size of this sheet.

Here is what I have tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(K2&L2,CHOOSE({1,2},{Indirect(E2) & INDIRECT(F2), Indirect(D2)},{1,2})))
=query(Arrayformula({INDIRECT(D2), Vlookup($K$2:$K$45 & $L$2:$L$45, {Indirect(E2) & INDIRECT(F2), Indirect(D2)}, false)}),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col10,Col17,Col24,Col31 where not Col1 is null",1
=ArrayFormula((VLOOKUP(K2,INDIRECT($D$3),{1,2,3,10,17,24,31})))
```

This is a very small example of what the final sheet will be. I included what I want the results to be on a separate tab.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-XNePmTzVIc84ScasZxh1KlzTBxDyI_glxwg24uXGuI/edit#gid=868379110

Comment: Add some examples of the formulas that you already tried and some data sample in the question body as the access to the linked spreadsheet might be lost.

Comment: I would recommend you keep track of all of your data on a single tab rather than having different tabs for each week.  That will make everything downstream much simpler.

Comment: Hi there @ColleenMcHugh! After evaluating your scenario I strongly suggest you to try [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to reach your goals. Would it be a valid answer for you?

Comment: @MattKing I would love to do that, however the is the program I am working with.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I haven't worked with scripts much at all so I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: @ColleenMcHugh I just responded to your same question on the Google Forums.  I'd prefer to try to handle it there if possible.

Comment: ColleenMcHugh, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script) you can get your first touch with Apps Script and run a sample script. If it is a valid approach for you, I could write the final code. If you found help in Google Forums as @MattKing said, please come back to share any useful info with us so we all can help you better.